# XML Schema to enforce 0 or 1 default values

Tags: xml, schema, constraints

I am trying to implement an XML Schema which will enforce the following the XML ;

```
<databases>
    <database>
        <name>"Test A"</name>
        <host>"192.168.0.100"</host>
        <default>yes</default>
    </database>
    <database>
        <name>"Test B"</name>
        <host>"192.168.0.200"</host>
        <default>no</default>        
    </database>
    <database>
        <name>"Test C"</name>
        <host>"localhost"</host>
        <default>no</default>        
    </database>
</databases>
```

I am able to implement the XML Schema myself except for one crucial issue; and that is that a maximum of only one database should be marked as the default. This means that zero databases could be marked as the default and this should also be considered valid.

As an example, the following XML should be considered invalid by the XML Schema, since more than one database is marked as default.

```
<databases>
    <database>
        <name>"Test A"</name>
        <host>"192.168.0.100"</host>
        <default>yes</default>
    </database>
    <database>
        <name>"Test B"</name>
        <host>"192.168.0.200"</host>
        <default>no</default>        
    </database>
    <database>
        <name>"Test C"</name>
        <host>"localhost"</host>
        <default>yes</default>        
    </database>
```

Whereas the following XML should be considered valid by the XML Schema since no (zero) databases are marked as default ;

```
<databases>
    <database>
        <name>"Test A"</name>
        <host>"192.168.0.100"</host>
        <default>no</default>
    </database>
    <database>
        <name>"Test B"</name>
        <host>"192.168.0.200"</host>
        <default>no</default>        
    </database>
    <database>
        <name>"Test C"</name>
        <host>"localhost"</host>
        <default>no</default>        
    </database>
```

Does anyone know if it is possible to enforce such a constraint with XML Schemas? I feel as though it should be, but I'm not sure how to go about implementing it.

Any assistance with respect to this matter would be immensely appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to check that only one database is marked as the default is probably to structure your XML differently:  record the databases as above, but drop the `default` element, and add an attribute or child element to the `databases` element which identifies the default database.  Your XML becomes:

```
<databases default="Test A">
    <database>
        <name>Test A</name>
        <host>"192.168.0.100"</host>
   </database>
    <database>
        <name>Test B</name>
        <host>"192.168.0.200"</host>
   </database>
    <database>
        <name>Test C</name>
        <host>"localhost"</host>
   </database>
</databases>
```

(I have dropped the quotation marks in the `name` elements, on the theory that they are not actually part of the database name.  If they are part of the name, then the default attribute will need to be something like `default='"Test A"'`, including the quotes.)

You will need to ensure that the `database/name` element is unique; do this with an `xs:key` construct in the declaration of the `databases` element.  You will also need to ensure that the optional `default` attribute points at a database name; do this with `xs:keyref`.  The declaration of `databases` might look something like this:

```
<xs:element name="databases" type="databases">
  <xs:key name="dbname">
    <xs:selector xpath="database"/>
    <xs:field xpath="name"/>
  </xs:key>
  <xs:keyref refer="dbname" name="defaultdb">
    <xs:selector xpath="."/>
    <xs:field xpath="@default"/>
  </xs:keyref>
</xs:element>
```

A second approach makes a slightly devious use of `xs:unique`, but again requires refactoring your XML.  Instead of making the third child of `database` be `default` with values `yes` or `no`, make the third child be either an element named `default-database` or an element named `non-default-database` (change the names to suit your preferences, of course).  Define these in such a way as to ensure that every instance of `default-database` has the same simple-type value.

Then specify that no two occurrences of `default-database` may have the same string value, using `xs:unique`:

```
<xs:unique name="dbname">
  <xs:selector xpath="database"/>
  <xs:field xpath="default-database"/>
</xs:unique>
```

Since every instance of `default-database` has the same value, this uniqueness constraint ensures that there can only ever be one such element.  The schema as a whole might look something like this.  First the bookkeeping:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  elementFormDefault="qualified">
```

Now the element declaration for `databases`:

```
  <xs:element name="databases" type="databases">
    <xs:unique name="dbname">
      <xs:selector xpath="database"/>
      <xs:field xpath="default-database"/>
    </xs:unique>
  </xs:element>
```

And its complex type:

```
  <xs:complexType name="databases">
    <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xs:element ref="database"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="default" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
  </xs:complexType>
```

Now some more bookkeeping:  declaration for `database`, just to keep us honest.

```
  <xs:element name="database" type="database"/>

  <xs:complexType name="database">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="host" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:choice>       
        <xs:element name="default-database" type="empty"/>
        <xs:element name="non-default-database" type="empty"/>
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
```

And a final bit of bookkeeping:  a type that ensures that every instance of `default-database` has the same value.  (There are other ways to achieve this, of course; this is just the one that came to mind first.)

```
  <xs:simpleType name="empty">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value=""/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType> 

</xs:schema>
```

If you are absolutely married to your existing design, then I don't know how to do what you want to do in XSD 1.0; if you can use XSD 1.1, of course, you can add an assertion on `databases` that says

```
<xs:assert test="count(database[default = 'yes']) = 1"/>
```

But as the alternative solutions above illustrate, that design and the use of assertions is not your only option.

Comment: An absolutely fantastic response. Some great suggestions which have been very well written. Thankyou so very much.